# HTML/CSS - linear gradient not taking up full screen

Tags: html, css, background, gradient, linear-gradients

If I have the following CSS property for my body:

```
body {

 background-color: red;
 background-image: linear-gradient(red, orange);
}
```

Then the gradient appears on my web page but it does not take up the full screen size (I have a big monitor). It appears as below: Is this a issue with the footer? I do not have a footer currently.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the white square  in the middle

Comment: Just a bunch of content I put a white square over in Paint. I figured the gradient had only to do with the background of the body of the page

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Answer (score 32):

Got the same problem but only this one is working, please add this style to your css

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

The `background-attachment` property sets whether a background image scrolls with the rest of the page, or is fixed. There are three values: `scroll`, `fixed`, and `local`. Works best with gradient background.

Check out the doc [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Try this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/297/)**

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: rgba(231,56,39,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231,56,39,1) 0%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 27%, rgba(255,166,0,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(231,56,39,1)), color-stop(27%, rgba(231,56,39,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,166,0,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231,56,39,1) 0%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 27%, rgba(255,166,0,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231,56,39,1) 0%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 27%, rgba(255,166,0,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231,56,39,1) 0%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 27%, rgba(255,166,0,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(231,56,39,1) 0%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 27%, rgba(255,166,0,1) 100%);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was actually the margin property.

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```